# Google Tag Manager script for dynamically generated page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a web page that is dynamically generated by a script (it's a member dashboard). I'm trying to track when someone clicks on a dropdown which changes their selection of a care provider. Unfortunately I cannot alter the source code at all, I must come up with a solution using GTM alone.

I have this code:

```
<script>
console.log('Hello!!');
function dropdownListen(){
  var matOption = document.querySelector("mat-select[name=providerSelect] .mat-select-value span span");
   console.log(matOption);
      var callback = function(){
        //window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
          "event": "selectionMade"
        });
      };
      
  matOption.addEventListener("change", callback);
}
window.onload = dropdownListen();
</script>
```

The first Hello! logs in the console, but the second logging matOption returns null. I have confirmed that the selector works using this codepen (I just copied the code I'm trying to target into the HTML) https://codepen.io/pointnine/pen/zYMZvBy?editors=1111

I *think* it may have to do with the code running before the page is loaded? I can't think of anything else. I currently have the custom HTML tag in GTM triggered on window load, but I've tried on DOM ready and page view which also doesn't help. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes normally it is the order issue.

Here is a way to check if it is window load already.

```
<script>
console.log('Hello!!');
function dropdownListen(){
  var matOption = document.querySelector("mat-select[name=providerSelect] .mat-select-value span span");
   console.log(matOption);
      var callback = function(){
        //window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
          "event": "selectionMade"
        });
      };
      
  matOption.addEventListener("change", callback);
}

// if it's already window load. Just execute the function
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  dropdownListen();
} else {
  window.onload = dropdownListen;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @darrelltw I gave it a try but matOption is still returning null.

Comment: If we change some direction. Will you able to modify the source code on the frontend? I take a look about mat-select and looks like it is from angular framework. If you can modify it within angular to listen the change and everything will become easier.

Comment: I wish I could but that's unfortunately not an option - managed by a different company.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're not using actual functionality of GTM rather than just using it to inject custom html?

You could deploy a click trigger in GTM that would be triggered by the click on the dropdown, then track it or do whatever you want with it. GTM doesn't need elements to exist in DOM on its execution since it doesn't add event listeners to them. GTM analyzes clicks upstream and checks the targets against its selectors.

Comment: Yes I did try that. Here's what GTM is registering as the click element:

HTMLSpanElement: html > body > div.cdk-overlay-container > div.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box > div.cdk-overlay-pane#cdk-overlay-0 > div.mat-select-panel-wrap.ng-tns-c82-6.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-transformPanelWrap.ng-star-inserted > div.ng-tns-c82-6.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-transformPanel.mat-select-panel.mat-primary.benefits-dropdown#mat-select-4-panel > mat-option.mat-option.mat-focus-indicator.ng-tns-c82-6.ng-star-inserted#mat-option-6 > span.mat-option-text

But the click id is empty.

Comment: I tried targeting #mat-select-4-panel but this doesn't work. I can't use the classes because they aren't unique or consistent for all users. Is there a way to track a certain class that is a descendant of a specific id? I think that's a custom script too, no? @BNazaruk please enlighten me if I'm missing something!

Comment: It's good that you posted the Click Element value and the html snippet. In the Click Element value, GTM awkwardly tells you that the click lands on something inside that panel. You can't select a parent and expect it to select its children unless you are specific about it. So be specific. Try using this selector: "#mat-select-4-panel *"

Comment: Yep, tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Well, debug it. See why the trigger failed, inspect the clicked element on it again, make sure it's what you expect.